# Timer 1 can't increment on external T1OSI source for PIC16f627A

Tags: pic, c, mplabx, pic16f

New to PIC programming

Trying to Simulate a [PIC16F627A](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40044F.pdf) TIMER 1 using MPLAB X IDE
where RB7/T1OSI increments, and it toggles RB4 through TMR1 ISR.

```
#include <stdio.h>


#include <xc.h



#pragma config WDTE = 0;

//timer1
//period 1 ms or every 100 T1CKI
//external from T1CKI rising edge (1 sec Period) T1OSCEN = 0; //
//PIN RB4

void interrupt Pulse_ISR (void)
{
    PORTBbits.RB4 = !PORTBbits.RB4;
    PIR1bits.TMR1IF = 0;
    TMR1L = 0x96;
    TMR1H = 0xFF;    
}


void Init (void)
{
    //Global Interrupt
    //Peripheral Interrupt
   //TMR1IE
   //1:8 prescalar
   //t = 1us*8*N    N = 100 
   //TMR1 = (2^16+1) - 100 = 65436 FF96

   TRISB4 = 0;//RB4 is output
   TRISB6 = 1;//RB6 and RB7 are input
   TRISB7 = 1;

  INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
  INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;
  PIE1bits.TMR1IE = 1;

  T1CONbits.T1CKPS = 0b11;//1:8
  T1CONbits.T1OSCEN = 1;//TMR1 increments on T1OSI RB7
  T1CONbits.TMR1CS = 1;




  TMR1L = 0x96;
  TMR1H = 0xFF;


  PORTBbits.RB4 = 1;

  T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 1;    
}

void main (void)
{
    Init ();

    //I will simulate a 1 ms pulse 50% Duty Cycle at T1CKI/RB6



    while(1);
}
```

I created a stimuli where I created a pulse on pin RB7 with period of 500us

[image]

and I watch the result throught IO pins

[image]

I build the project and Debug it, watch RB4 IO Pins and it never toggles.

Can someone tell me why? Thank you.

MPLAB X IDE v3.55
PIC16F627A
Debugging Tool: Simulator

Comment: If you add a debug breakpoint in the ISR, does it ever execute that code?

Comment: You might also need to set LVP off, otherwise RB4 will be used as PGM, and won't work as a digital output.

Comment: @RogerRowland No it doesn't

Comment: @RogerRowland, I don't think that's the case, because before I got this issue, I did the same thing with RB6/T1CKI... 
(same code with the only difference T1OSCEN = 1;//to enable T1OSO), and it worked.

Comment: @RogerRowland, I read something at the PIC16F627A Manual, that I think might be related. Page 53 of the Manual 

"A crystal oscillator circuit is built in between pins T1OSI
(input) and T1OSO (amplifier output). It is enabled by
setting control bit T1OSCEN (T1CON<3>). It will
continue to run during Sleep. It is primarily intended for
a 32.768 kHz watch crystal. Table 7-1 shows the
capacitor selection for the Timer1 oscillator.
The user must provide a software time delay to ensure
proper oscillator start-up."

This I don't understand what it means?

Comment: Does It executes any of the code or It hangs in there?
Also I think you should use the "clock stimulus"...not sure about that tho.

Comment: @zakkos well if I step into it, it will stay at the `while(1);`, if I put a breakpoint at the begining of `Pulse_ISR (void)` and run the debugging simulation, the code will not reach the breakpoint.

Comment: @zakkos it worked with RB6/T1CKI, don't think the problem with what stimulus I used.

Comment: You have a typo in your code, a missing bracket in `#include <xc.h>` This has nothing to do with your problem but might be a minor hassle if you then want to copy/paste this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

From page 170 of the MPLAB® IDE User’s Guide about the simulation capabilities on 14-bit core PICs:

> Timer1 in its various modes is supported, except when running in counter mode by an external crystal.

Comment: I tried searching it on MPLAB X IDE couldn't find it, but maybe that makes sense of why it wasn't working on simulation.

Comment: I tried your code and it didn't work for me either but it somehow worked if I injected the clock on the `T1OSO`pin. Since, if you're using a crystal, you'd have both pins connected to it you may try simulating your program with that workaround.